# React update page with input info when pressing a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

react newbie here once again.
I'm trying to update the page with a note when pressing 'send' button.
Honestly I tried for so long that I think my code is pretty much a mess rn.

Main func:

```
function MainLogged() {

    const [sendingScreen, setSendingScreen] = useState(true);
    let notes = [];
    const [note, setNote] = useState('')

    function onNoteChange(event){
        const {value} = event.target;
        setNote(value);
    }

    function afterButtonClick(event) {
        notes.push(note);


        setSendingScreen((prev) => !prev)
    }

    return (
    <div id='main'>
        {sendingScreen ? <MainBody noteCallback={onNoteChange} callback={afterButtonClick}/> : <ResetScreen callback={afterButtonClick}/> }
        {console.log(notes)}
        { 
            notes.map((singleNote) => { 
                return (<p id='single-note' className='note'>{singleNote}</p>)
            })
        }
    </div>
 )
}
```

then goes to component:

```
function MainBody(props) {

    const {noteCallback, callback} = props;


    return (
        <div>
            <p id='main-body'>{lorem}</p>
            <div className='card text-center' style={{width: '18rem', alignSelf: 'center'}}>
                <Input onChange={noteCallback} type='text' placeholder='My note is...' className='card-body information' />
            </div>
            <SendCardButton callback = {callback}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and finally (if necessary):

```
function SendCardButton(props){

    const {callback} = props;
    return (
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-success toBeCentered" onClick={callback}>Send</button>
    )
}
```

Using this code leaves notes array empty always.

Please if you can explain so I can learn and improve, I REALLY need it right now.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you also will want to use a React.useState([]) as the empty notes then you can add a note with setNotes([...notes, note]). This way react knows to manage notes and update the dom if it changes.

Comment: As @ColinHale said, if you want your component to 'react' to `notes` changes you need to declare it as an state var

Answer (score 1):

React does not rerender your component after you click the button because notes are not stored in state. You need declare notes this way:

```
const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
```

And then set them on button click, not just push the new one:

```
setNotes((prevNotes) => ([...prevNotes, note]));
```

That should be enough:) Feel free to comment if you have further questions

Comment: I understand the logic, you are right but it's still not working... I think something im 'passing' is wrong(?)

Comment: Here is the working code in jsFiddle. I got rid of the stuff that doesn't have to do anything with the problem and changed the two lines from the original answer. https://jsfiddle.net/se80vLdh/12/